# UITableView inside of UICollectionViewCell reusing wrong cells

Tags: swift

I am trying to make an ingredient categorizer using a list of a list of ingredients.

```swift
typealias MasterIngredientList = [[IngredientItem]]
```

I currently have 5 categories of foods, so each index is a list that contains one category of the foods. I display this list of lists by using a UICollectionView and have each cell in that collection view be a UITableView that displays the items. I do this by having the cellForRowAt for the UICollectionView give a list to the cell instance then displaying them in the cells instance of the tableview.

Code in the ViewController for loading the cells :

```swift
func collectionView(
  _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
  numberOfItemsInSection section: Int
) -> Int {
  return recipeIngredients.count
}

func collectionView(
  _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
  cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = recipeIngredientCollectionView
    .dequeueReusableCell(
      withReuseIdentifier: "ingredientCatagoryCell",
      for: indexPath
    ) as! IngredientCatagoryCell
  // RecipeIngredients is the list of lists
  cell.ingredients = recipeIngredients[indexPath.row]
  print(indexPath.row)
  return cell
}
```

```swift
import UIKit

class IngredientCatagoryCell: UICollectionViewCell,
  UITableViewDelegate,
  UITableViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet var ingredientsTableView: UITableView!
  var ingredients: [IngredientItem] = []

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    ingredientsTableView.delegate = self
    ingredientsTableView.dataSource = self
    ingredientsTableView.register(
      UINib(nibName: "IngredientTableViewCell", bundle: nil),
      forCellReuseIdentifier: "ingredientCell"
    )
    ingredientsTableView.rowHeight = 100.0
    ingredientsTableView.reloadData()
  }

  private func printNames() {
    ingredients.forEach { item in
      print(item.name!)
    }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return ingredients.count
  }

  func tableView(
    _ tableView: UITableView,
    cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath
  ) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ingredientsTableView
      .dequeueReusableCell(
        withIdentifier: "ingredientCell",
        for: indexPath
      ) as! IngredientTableViewCell
    cell.ingredientImage.image = ingredients[indexPath.row].image
    cell.ingredientNameLabel.text = ingredients[indexPath.row].name.capitalized
    // print(self.ingredients[indexPath.row].name)
    return cell
  }
}
```

The problem that I'm currently running into is that even though each cell is given is own list to load tableview cells with, the tableview cells are being reused in the wrong places.

Each lists elements

```swift
private var dairyNames: [String] = ["cheese", "milk", "yogurt"]
private var fruitNames: [String] = [
  "apple", "avocado", "banana", "blueberries", "cherry", "coconut",
  "cranberry", "grapefruit", "grapes", "guava", "kiwi", "lemon",
  "lime", "mango", "olives", "orange", "papaya", "peach", "pear",
  "pineapple", "plum", "pomegranate", "raspberries", "strawberry",
  "tomato", "watermelon",
]
private var grainsNames: [String] = []
private var proteinNames: [String] = [
  "anchovy", "bacon", "beef", "catfish", "chicken", "clams", "crab",
  "duck", "ham", "lamb", "lobster", "meatballs", "oyster", "salami",
  "salmon", "sardines", "sausage", "scallop", "shrimp", "turkey",
]
private var vegetableNames: [String] = [
  "artichoke", "arugula", "asparagus", "bamboo", "beet", "broccoli",
  "brussels-sprouts", "cabbage", "carrot", "cauliflower", "celery", "corn",
  "cucumber", "eggplant",
]
```

A Video showing the improper reuse of cells, specifically the 4th collectioncell doesn't display all the protein elements and just reuses the cells from the dairy list. Then in the last collectioncell the first few cells are used from the 2nd collectioncells' tableview cells. I then have to scroll down and back up for the correct cells to be loaded.

[Video link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlsvD.jpg)

How do I get the correct cells to load for each collectionview cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `ingredientsTableView.reloadData()` from awakeFromNib and reload your tableView inside cellForItemAt instead:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
 let cell = recipeIngredientCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ingredientCatagoryCell",for: indexPath) as! IngredientCatagoryCell
 // RecipeIngredients is the list of lists
 cell.ingredients = recipeIngredients[indexPath.item] // change indexPath.row to indexPath.item 
 cell.ingredientsTableView.reloadData() 
print(indexPath.row)
return cell
}
```